# Does the strong Markov property hold for Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

given a Brownian motion $B(t)_{t\geq 0}$, I am trying to prove that Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $X_{t}=e^{-t}B_{e^{2t}}$ holds the strong Markov property. Any hints?

Comment: I am trying to decipher what is written on page 391 of "Walsh - Knowing the odds: an introduction to probability". 
There (page 391, point 5°) it claims that the strong Markov property of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process "follows from the strong Markov property of Brownian motion", but I cannot manage to understand how I can extend the properties of $B_{t}$ to $X_{t}$